# Read complete CSV cell data for complicated strings

Tags: ruby, string, csv

I am using ruby to merge CSV files that might contain different headers.
my problem is that some of the values in the CSV files are quite complicated and when data get lost in the merge process

for example the original value:
 `"[cell([""A"",""B""]),""X""+cell([""A"",""C""])+""W""].join(""_"")"`
 will be written as `"[cell([""A"",v1,""B""]),`
and as a result I get `CSV::MalformedCSVError (CSV::MalformedCSVError)` when trying to read the merged file.

how can I read and write the exact content of each CSV cell?
my code and running example:

```
def join_multiple_csv(csv_path_array)
  f = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_path_array[0]), :headers => true, :quote_char => "'")
  f_h = {}
  f.headers.each {|header| f_h[header] = f[header]}
  n_rows = f.size
  csv_path_array.shift(1)
  csv_path_array.each do |csv_file|
  curr_csv = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_file), :headers => true, :quote_char => "'")  
  curr_h = {}
  curr_csv.headers.each {|header| curr_h[header] = curr_csv[header]}
    new_headers = curr_csv.headers - f_h.keys
    exist_headers = curr_csv.headers - new_headers
    new_headers.each { |new_header|
      f_h[new_header] = Array.new(n_rows) + curr_csv[new_header]
    }
    exist_headers.each {|exist_header|
      f_h[exist_header] = f_h[exist_header] + curr_csv[exist_header]
    }
    n_rows = n_rows + curr_csv.size
  end
  csv_headers = f_h.keys.map {|string| string}
  output = csv_headers.join(",") + "\n"
  (0..n_rows-1).each do |i|
    row = ''
    f_h.each_key do |header|
      if f_h[header][i].nil?
        row.concat(f_h[header][i].to_s + ",")
      else
        row.concat(f_h[header][i].to_s + ",")
      end
    end
    output.concat(row + "\n")
  end
  return output
end

csv_files = ['f1.csv', 'f2.csv']
outputs = join_multiple_csv(csv_files)
f = CSV.new(outputs)
row = f.readline
while row do
  row = f.readline
end
```

running example:
f1.csv

```
H1,H3,H4
v1,v2,v3
```

f2.csv

```
H2,H3,H4
v1,v3,"[cell([""A"",""B""]),""X""+cell([""A"",""C""])+""W""].join(""_"")"
```

expected output:

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
v1,,v2,v3
,v1,v3,"[cell([""A"",""B""]),""X""+cell([""A"",""C""])+""W""].join(""_"")"
```

output:

```
H1,H3,H4,H2,
v1,v2,v3,,,
,v3,"[cell([""A"",v1,""B""]),
,,,,,
,,,,,
```

Any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I answered in rush.

I tried to run your program and found that the quote character causing to split the cell value on each comma in the string. changing quote character to double quote worked for me

```
f = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_path_array[0]), :headers => true, :quote_char => '"')



curr_csv = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_file), :headers => true, :quote_char => '"')
```

Comment: that worked for you? The original data is not preserved and I get  ```Illegal quoting on line 3. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)```

Comment: yes, it worked for me. Try printing `outputs` before `f = CSV.new(outputs)`